# Vue CLI 3 using index pug to generate pug template

Tags: webpack-4, vue-cli-3, pug-loader

I am using Vue CLI 3 with built in Webpack and I am trying to use `index.pug` as source index template instead of default HTML. I want to output a `index.pug` file as a result of webpack process for further population by Node server with dynamic data.

Here is my `vue.config.js`:

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const resolve = (dir) => {
  return path.join(__dirname, '.', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'server/app'),
  baseUrl: process.env.ENV === 'production' ? process.env.VUE_APP_CDN_URL + 'app/' : '/',
  configureWebpack: {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    entry: {
      app: './client/main.js'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
      alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
        '@': resolve('client')
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './public/index.pug',
        inject: true
      }),
    ]
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('pug')
      .test(/\.pug$/)
      .use('pug-loader')
        .loader('pug-loader')
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, above fails with:

```
Error: Child compilation failed:
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Some thoughts and assumptions:

- `configureWebpack` seems to be setup correctly (https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#chaining-advanced)
- *HtmlWebpackPlugin* might not be the plugin to use since its purpose is to generate HTML file as output, but I cant even get that to complete successfully

Unfortunately, there is not a whole lot of documentation online on this topic, so hoping for help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Likely not a direct answer but we had to add the generated scripts to JSPs. An alternate is to use a [ManifestPlugin](https://github.com/danethurber/webpack-manifest-plugin) and create a list of generated assets per entry file and append them to the index.pug.

I have an open issue but you can use their [generate](https://github.com/danethurber/webpack-manifest-plugin/issues/181) function to come up with ways to dice the assets the way you prefer.

Comment: This could work, but seems like a hack to resolve something that should be configurable via VueCLI/Webpack. Do you have code sample for how you use ManifestPlugin to extract assets and inject into index.pug?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to support a configurable config. Until then take a look at the generate deep link that shows how you can use the generate function to create your own manifest.